# How to test for people in a radius not centered on command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to use the `testfor` command in Minecraft to test for people in a radius not centered on the command block?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `testfor @p[r=5,x=1,y=65,z=89]`

If you use then in front you can leave the x, y, z and r out
`testfor @p[5,65,89,5]`